# Compare File & Copy Replace if Successful

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, size, backup

I have written a shell script that creates a backup of my MySQL database. The script performs the following functions:

1. Creates a Backup of the MySQL database
2. Compresses the Backup
3. Copies the Backup to a Remote Server
4. Send an E-Mail displaying the size of the Backup
5. Removes any left over files on the source server not needed.

What the script doesn't do, but what I need it to do:

1. Check the newly created Backup against the existing backup on the remote server
2. If the new backup is smaller than the old backup, send a WARNING Notification via e mail / sms.
3. If the new backup is larger or equal in size to the old backup, replace the old backup on the remote server with the new backup and then send the successful notification stated in point 4.

Thanks, any help here is really appreciated

Operating systems being used:

Source Server: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Destination Server: Fedora release 13 (Goddard)

Comment: Which means of connection are available from the source to the destination server (FTP, SCP, NFS, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on file size. Use the date stamp and keep a rolling set of backups so you always have the last 5 days' worth of backups. rsync is what I would use.

Comment: I want to use the files size merely to see if the backup has increased in size. Due to space limitation, I am replacing the backup on a daily basis, which is why I need to do the check on size.